# What relation does Image Synthesis from the third game, have to Grathmelding from the first game?

Tags: ar-tonelico

What relation does Image Synthesis from the third game, have to Grathmelding from the first game?

Because [the Meld~ songs](https://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/Ar_tonelico_Qoga:_Knell_of_Ar_Ciel_Original_Soundtrack) of the third game all say "Glassmerk", at the beginning, and sound like the first game's song for Grathmelding, and "Glassmerk" is the Japanese version of "Grathmeld".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have no relationship: Grathmelding was developed in Sol Ciel long after the Grathnode Inferia, so there is no way it could have spread to the other regons. Image Synthesis is just typical synthesis, and the synthesis music for it only has these titles as a callback to AT1, similarly to how the world map themes ("Green Lands" and "Azure Lands") from both games sound quite similar to each other.